# Producer metric: record_error_rate ,when will this value be greater than zero

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, jmx, kafka-producer-api

I am checking and validating the metrics of producer and consumers. But metric `record_error_rate` is always seems to be zero in all my experiments.

If someone has any ideas when will this be non-zero then please let me know, also the steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in record-error-rate ? There should be dashes not underscores.

Comment: yes, you are right, it is '-' and not '_'

Answer (score 0):

[`record-error-rate`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#per-broker-metrics) indicates the average per-second number of record sends that resulted in errors for a topic.

---

If you get `0` then it simply means that no record has failed from the producer side.

---

Now if for testing purposes you want to intentionally get a non-zero value then simply try to generate a faulty message from the producer side. For example, try to send a message with a wrong schema, withoug authentication (if SSL is enabled), etc.

Comment: So, is it because of client side errors, will this also include errors in case producer fails to publish messages because of either brokers are down, network partition, I mean server side or network errors

Comment: Tried locally with while ValueSerializer was String but send Integer, mentioned metrics value still 0.  Also same metric is available at topic level and even a consolidated value at producer instance level as well. Will try with authentication as well

Comment: @dvsakgec Any luck?

Comment: Hi @dvsakgec, any update on it? :))) I have the same problem, when send fails with time out, it logs it in error total but it does not log it to error rate

Comment: Sorry guys, pretty late. No luck tried but could not reproduce.